# ASP.NET Membership Provider logging out when passing query string

Tags: vb.net, query-string, membership-provider

I'm using ASP.NET Membership Provider. My problem is that when a user is logged in, clicks to go do a different page and passes a query string in the process, when they reach the new page with the query string appended to the URL, the Membership Provider doesn't recognize they are still logged in.

At this point if they log in again, then they can continue to click to different pages with query strings and stay logged in. But the issue is that the first time a query string is passed, it essentially logs them out.

Is there a way to authenticate the user on membership pages regardless of the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom memebership provider?

have you tried something similar to the following...

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username, False)
```

Regards

Comment: I haven't tried doing a RedirectFromLoginPage, but I'm not sure I understand how that would solve my problem. The issue is that I'm losing authentication on certain pages. I'm not interested in redirecting back into the login page and then redirecting them back to the new page.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding? Is there a way to reset a cookie on pages with a query string? Or pass authentication forward on the redirect? Or maybe add authentication for those pages in the web.config?